Specflow scenario with 2 tags, failing to locate tag names in Jenkins run
I am trying to use multiple tags for a scenario outline in Specflow C# feature file. I need this implementation because of a change in functionality based on tag names.
@User1 @User2
Scenario Outline: Test login for users
Given Login using API

Examples:
| Env name | Test Data Sheet path | Test Set name |

NOTE: The data in the examples tag is read in the code and functionality is working if I give only 1 tag name.
But when I give 2 tag names and give the run through Jenkins, Jenkins doesn't recognize the tag names and the Jenkins job run fails with the error

Feature Tag : "User1" is not found -> If I try to give run with first tag name
Feature Tag : "User2" is not found -> If I try to give run with second tag name

Is there a way to run both tag names individually through Jenkins even if they are given together to a scenario.

How exactly are you running the tests in Jenkins? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

And are you using both SpecFlow AND Cucumber? Those are two different tools.
